# after popup gets open background as well as header also should get grayout

Tags: angularjs

$mdDialog.show({
controller: userPRefrencesController,
templateUrl: '../App/Views/UserPrefrencesTable.html',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
targetEvent: ev,
clickOutsideToClose: false,
fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
})

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you want in the question ,
is the question is 'how to get a grey background ?'
then the answer is set `hasBackdrop` to `true`.

```
$mdDialog.show({ 
    controller: userPRefrencesController,
    templateUrl: '../App/Views/UserPrefrencesTable.html', 
    parent: angular.element(document.body), 
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: false, 
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
    hasBackdrop : true
})
```

If the question is 'how to add the grey background to header as well ?'.

Then the answer is to decrease the z-index of the header in css.